# Does ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance work with nullable types in constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I have such constructor:

```
public UserGroupEditViewModel(IMediator mediator, int? userGroupId)
    {
        Model = new()
        {
            UserGroupId = userGroupId
        };

        this.mediator = mediator;
    }
```

When I'm trying to pass `null` as value of `userGroupId` it ends up with inability to find suitable constructor. However, when I pass, for example, `1` as `userGroupId` it works fine!

Could you please help find workaround for this issue?

Code responsible for instantiating:

```
public TViewModel Create<TViewModel>(params object[] viewModelParameters)
        where TViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<TViewModel>(serviceProvider, viewModelParameters);
    }
```

Comment: It still ends up as `(object)null` in `Create` method, so there's no clue

Comment: Actually, how are you calling `Create`? Can you show a [mcve]?